# SherlockDialogFragment and empty space on dialog

Tags: android, layout, dialog, android-dialogfragment

How to delete clean space on top dialog?

To display I extends my class SherlockDialogFragment. Maybe try to change the setStyle?

My layout of dialog:

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="10dp" >

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/pbDialog"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDialog"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text="text" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My screen:

[image: screen with spaces]

Answer (score 2):

Working:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME, android.R.style.Theme);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Max Bublifoff for your input.  His will give you no frame as stated.  If you want to keep the dialog frame use this in the onCreate.

```
    setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
   override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
      requireDialog().requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
      return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
   }
```